# How can I calculate averaged response curves for Maxent models fitted using maxnet package in R?

Tags: r, graph, replication, maxent

Could someone please point me towards an efficient approach?
plot and response.plot (maxnet package) can produce response curves for individual models, but feeding a list of model replicates, as generated when fitting models in a for-loops using different sets of occurrences, fails.
Any idea or comments?

My models are created in a similar way as in the following example:

```
require(maxnet)
data("bradypus")
presences <- which(x = bradypus$presence == 1)
absences <- which(x = bradypus$presence == 0)

my_models <- list()
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:3) {

maxnet_data <- bradypus[c(sample(x = presences,
                                 size = 25,
                                 replace = F),
                          sample(x = absences,
                                 size = 25,
                                 replace = F)),]

my_models[[i]] <- maxnet(p = maxnet_data[, 1], data = maxnet_data[, -1],
                         f = maxnet.formula(p = maxnet_data[, 1],
                         data = maxnet_data[, -1], classes = "lq"))
}
```

Comment: Can you give actual code,  perhaps using sample data or simulated data, that illustrates your problem and what you are trying to get out? Makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: @Spacedman I added an example of the data I have to deal with. The problem is getting mean response curves representing the average across models.

Comment: How do you get the mean response values from a *single* model?

Comment: @Spacedman the samplemeans are accessible via `my_models[[i]]$samplemeans`

Comment: So do you want the mean of the data that draws the plots from `plot(onemodel)` for each variable for each model?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, `plot(x = my_models[[1]], type = "cloglog")` conveniently produces the single model plots. The java version (Maxent) is able to draw mean response curves which also show the variation between models. No hint in the R maxnet helpfiles though.

Comment: Unpicking the code in `response.plot` tells me the plots come from `predict` on the model. So you can call `response.plot` with `plot=FALSE` and get the values back, but these are evaluated at different values depending on the model so you can't just average them. Solution is create a `newdata` frame for each variable and call `predict` with the same one for each model and average.

Comment: So I think I can see how to do this but I *really* have other things to do now. See how far you can get with `predict` and the code in `response.plot` and post an edit in the Q or a half-answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of function that get you 90% of the way. Its hacked out of response.plot:

```
#' get the responses for variable v in a list of models
#' use min and max for the range of the variable, this is
#' fixed for each model
#'
#' for a categorical variable, it uses the levels instead
#' Based on response.plot
#' 
responses = function (mods, v, type, min, max){

    vlevels = unlist(mods[[1]]$levels[v])

    mv <- if (!is.null(vlevels)) 
              vlevels
          else seq(min - 0.1 * (max - min), max + 0.1 * (max - min), 
                   length = 100)

    allpreds = lapply(mods, function(mod){
        mm = mod$samplemeans
        nr <- if (is.null(vlevels)) 
                  100
              else length(vlevels)
        m <- data.frame(matrix(mm, nr, length(mm), byrow = T))
        colnames(m) <- names(mm)
        m[, v] <- mv
        preds <- predict(mod, m, type = type)
        return(preds)
    })

    list(
        allpreds = do.call(cbind,allpreds),
        v = mv
    )
}

#' Given a list of models and some data from which to compute
#' the ranges, get all the responses
#' 
allresponses <- function(models, data, var, type="link"){
    if(is.null(levels(data[[var]]))){
        minv = min(data[[var]])
        maxv = max(data[[var]])
    }else{
        minv=NA
        maxv=NA
    }
    responses(models,var, type=type, minv, maxv)
}
```

Then for your test data:

```
> frs6190 = allresponses(my_models, bradypus, "frs6190_ann")
> str(frs6190)
List of 2
 $ allpreds: num [1:100, 1:3] 0.889 0.889 0.889 0.889 0.889 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ v       : num [1:100] -20 -17.6 -15.2 -12.7 -10.3 ...
>
```

So for that variable, the three model responses are in `frs6190$allpreds`, and you can plot them:

```
 matplot(frs6190$v, frs6190$allpreds,type="l",lty=1)
```

[image]

So if you want the average response for that variable, apply `mean` across the `allpreds` elements.

To do for all variables, loop over all the variable names in an `apply` or other iterative control structure.

Hope this is what you are after...

Comment: Great work! Thanks! I will expand your answer should I succeed in getting the plots (thanks to your code and hints I should be able!). Currently, working on other parts of the paper but coming back to it for the figures. Again, thank you!

Comment: To plot the mean across models: `matplot(frs6190$v, rowMeans(x = frs6190$allpreds, na.rm = T), type="l", lty=1)` This requires the Matrix package being loaded. For anyone using the recent maxent/maxnet and following this, please note that `allresponses(my_models, bradypus, "frs6190_ann")` should be run with `type = "cloglog"`.